# Executing sequence of spark jobs using nohup commands automatically

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, nohup

I need to load historical data to hive tables based on various file partitions. Spark submits are currently being invoked using nohup commands. I am trying to create a script that will contain all nohup commands which will execute sequentially after a successful completion of first nohup command.

I tried

```
nohup 1
if [ ? = 0 ]; then
nohup 2
```

But the next nohup2 command starts executing before completion of spark job in nohup1.

Current script:

```
nohup sh /home/spark_load1.sh
#After successful load1, start the next nohup
nohup sh /home/spark_load2.sh
#After successful load2, start the next nohup
nohup sh /home/spark_load3.sh
```

I want to second nohup execution to happen only if the previous nohup was successful.

```
nohup sh /home/spark_load1.sh
#After successful load1, start the next nohup
nohup sh /home/spark_load2.sh
#After successful load2, start the next nohup
nohup sh /home/spark_load3.sh
```

Comment: i dont think this is the best way, have you considered using an orchestration tool like airflow for this

Comment: what about not using nohup?

Comment: @thebluephantom - Design of the project has been made in such a way that a wrapper shell script invokes spark submit. Could you tell me how i can execute without nohup?

Comment: Nohup on a main LINUX script calling other scripts with nohup. I am not working in LINUX etc. at the moment so I cannot check, but this I seem to remeber. I would also be using a scheduling tool, Oozie, Airflow or some of the other community edition tools.

Comment: try to invoke next nohup execution based on the process id of the first one, like while(!{process_id}){"sleep 1s"}

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on this way:

```
nohup sh /home/spark_load1.sh && sh /home/spark_load2.sh && sh /home/spark_load3.sh
```

And do not forget to add ampersand `&` on the end, otherwise if your connection broke will stop the script.
Also is good practice to use so name shebang to avoid running every time externally the shell (add this as first line in your shell scripts and make them executable)

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
```

In this case the line will be shorter

```
nohup /home/spark_load1.sh && /home/spark_load2.sh && /home/spark_load3.sh
```